# ERROR: venv: commands failed while installing devstack on ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, devstack

I am trying to install devstack on ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

While installing I came across this error. Up to this I edited `local.conf` file. Installed libvirt-1.2.15.

The detail screenshot is as follows:

```
venv create: /opt/stack/tempest/.tox/venv
venv installdeps: -r/opt/stack/tempest/requirements.txt, -r/opt/stack/tempest/test-requirements.txt
venv develop-inst: /opt/stack/tempest
venv runtests: PYTHONHASHSEED='1819679666'
venv runtests: commands[0] | verify-tempest-config -uro ../../../tmp/tmp.rVlU7KbPiF
Running config verification...
**ERROR: InvocationError: '/opt/stack/tempest/.tox/venv/bin/verify-tempest-config -uro ../../../tmp/tmp.rVlU7KbPiF'
___________________________________ summary ____________________________________
ERROR:   venv: commands failed**
+ exit_trap
+ local r=1
++ jobs -p
+ jobs=
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ kill_spinner
+ '[' '!' -z '' ']'
+ [[ 1 -ne 0 ]]
+ echo 'Error on exit'
Error on exit
+ [[ -z /opt/stack/logs ]]
+ /home/stack/devstack/tools/worlddump.py -d /opt/stack/logs
World dumping... see /opt/stack/logs/worlddump-2015-05-12-152538.txt for details
+ exit 1
stack@stack:~/devstack$
```